# I want to show an image when it shows Webpage not available

Tags: android, android-webview, mobile-webkit

I'm looking for solution regarding the WebView Android app. I want to show an image whenever the screen shows Webpage Not Available. I tried looking for solutions but they didn't work. Please Help Me.

In MainActivity.java

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
    public void  onReceivedError (WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);

            findViewById(R.id.customError).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    });
```

And in activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splashLoading"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:src="@mipmap/splash_loading"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/customError"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_error"
    />


<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to replace `this` with `getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 1):

One simple way would be to have `ImageView` and `WebView` inside a `RelativeLayout` and keep the `imageView` above `webView`. Initially keep `imageView` invisible, and inside your `onReceivedError` method, make the `imageView` visible.